# AdMob crashes when trying to load request

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, admob

I' cant get solution on this one. I have two projects, one is complete written in Swift and the other one is bit older, so its mixed with Swift and Objective C classes.

In both projects I am using Google Firebase Analytics, Crash Reporting, Database and AdMob.

I am installing Firebase with CocoaPods. It successfully installing all required pods from both pod files.

But on older projects its just AdMob the problem. I cant get it to work, I tried almost everything. From clearing all pods and installing it again, or importing GoogleMobileAds framework manually. I have -ObjC in other linker flags, so this os not a problem here. 
I have also added:

`(NSAllowsArbitraryLoads, NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMedia,
NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent)`

to App Transport Security Settings like AdMob tutorial page is presenting.

Xcode recognize framework and I am able to writte the code. And everything works fine. But when I build and run my app there is just nothing happening.

In my newer project where AdMob is working fine I get logs like:

```
<Google> To get test ads on this device, call: request.testDevices = @[ @"2d5255c02879582904ab5f6ef80dc59f" ];
```

So I know that AdMob is configuring. I am also able to present banners and other ads.

But on my older one, no single AdMob related log happens.
And if I'm trying to present banner app crashes when I am trying to load request with error:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSTaggedPointerString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa000000000062662'
```

I've seen some topics related to this crash with no solutions (except deleting project and starting a fresh one).

Answer (score 0):

Check your Info.plist's **LSApplicationQueriesSchemes** value or its type. In my case, it was incorrect and led to this crash.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same issue

> [NSTaggedPointerString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0xa000000000062662

I fixed it by changing the `info.plist=>>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` and changed the type to **array** instead of **string**.

Hope its helpful.
Thank You.